# How to clear the custom field on contact when there is Activity History?

Tags: apex, contact, tasks

I need to reset a custom field on the contact object when there is an Activity History of some type.

Should I write trigger on the Task Object or on the Contact object? If I write a trigger on the contact object how to get reference to the Task Object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a trigger on Task, since it is that record that you will want to check for changes.

Then you can get a reference to the Contact object via the `WhoId` field.

See [Task](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_task.htm) and [Task and Event Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_activities.htm).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below trigger to solve your problem.

```
trigger haveActivities on Task(after insert) {
    set<Id> contactId = new Set<Id>();
    Map<Id,Id> mapTaskContact = new Map<Id,Id>();
    Map<Id,Boolean> mapContactBoolean = new Map<Id,Id>();
    List<Contact> lstContact = new List<Contact>();
    for(Task t : trigger.new) {
        if(t.whoId.subString(0,3) == Contact.sObjectType.getDescribe().getKeyPrefix()) {
            contactId.add(t.whoId);
            mapTaskContact.put(t.Id,t.whoId);
        }
    }
    for(Contact c : [Select Id,CustomField__c From Contact Where Id In : contactId]) {
        mapContactBoolean.put(c.Id,false);
        if(c.CustomField__c != NULL && c.CustomField__c != '')
            mapContactBoolean.put(c.Id,true);
    }
    for(Task t : trigger.new) {
        if(mapTaskContact.get(t.Id) != NULL && mapContactBoolean.get(t.whoId)) {
            lstContact.add(new Contact(Id=t.whoId,CustomField__c = NULL));
        }
    }
    update lstContact;
}
```

You need to write the same trigger on Event object as well.

Hope it helps.